# CSS: Divs/articles not sitting underneath header - positioning issue

Tags: css, sass, css-position, positioning

Wondering if you could help. Going around the houses with this one on google.

Basically, I'm trying to build a website in SASS, not using any css frameworks intentionally.  But I'm having an issue making my two articles, appear under my header/header image...  Here's how the site currently looks:

https://reenaverma.github.io/

The problem is, I have some javascript on the header, where if you move your mouse across the image, the images pans in whichever direction the mouse moves.  This seems to only work, if the header is set at: **position: absolute;**

As a result, my articles sit on top of/within my header.

If I remove the **position: absolute**, only then, do my articles sit below the header.  But then the javascript doesn't work...

Here's relevant the CSS/SASS I'm using so far:

```
header {
 // background-image: url(https://kordastudio.hu/wp- 
 content/uploads/2017/01/blade-runner-2049_.jpg);
 background-image: url(/assets/images/futuristic_background.jpg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 /* Preserve aspet ratio */
 min-width: 110%;
 min-height: 500px;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 align-content: center;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 // position:relative;
 // padding:10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh; /* make sure wrapper is taller enough */
 border: solid thin #060;
 // overflow: hidden; /* Add this */
}


.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
 }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
 }

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
<main>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>about me</li>
      <li>projects</li>
      <li>timeline</li>
      <li>linkedin</li>
      <li>github</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Background image and title -->

    <div class="container">

      <header id="header" class="gradient flex-item">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </header>

    <!-- grey container -->
      <article class="flex-item">
        text
      </article>

      <article class="flex-item">
        text
      </article>

</div>
<main>
```

Really annoying!  Struggling with this one!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I actually got it working.  Basically, there was something wrong with the code of my container and flex-item.  I found another flex solution, which prevented the need for position absolute AND keeps my boxes below.

Not sure exactly what it was, but here's the new code below.  I wrapped this around the articles i wanted to appear underneath the header...

```
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -50;
}
.flex-grid .col {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a chance with this, but I think you can try with

For the banner

```
position: relative;
```

Or set a div for header and set a height for the banner if you want a fix height for the banner.

For the 2 flex item, wrap in a new

```
<div>
    <article class="flex-item"></article>
    <article class="flex-item"></article> 
</div>
```

Haven't test out the code yet, but let me know if it doesn't work, then I will try to run the code :)